# How to check if all items in a list are of the same type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, types

I'm trying to have a function validate that all items in a list are of the same type. See "check for integer type" section. However, that section of my function returns False no matter the input at the moment.

What would be the best way to have that section check for the type of input (float, string, integer), return False if they are not all the same, and return True otherwise? And have the function ask for another input if they are not of all the same type.

```
def max_of_three():

    # Ask users to input values
    value1 = input('Enter the first value here:  \n')
    value2 = input('Enter the second value here:  \n')
    value3 = input('Enter the third value here:  \n')

    # Store values in a list
    maxlist = [value1, value2, value3]
    maxlist.sort()

    # Check for integer type across the list:
    value = all(isinstance(item, int) for item in maxlist)
    print(value)

#    except:
#        print('Please ensure all inputs are of the same type!')

    #print the values
    print('\n')
    print('The maximum of these values is: \n', maxlist[-1])

max_of_three()
```

Edit:

I've now tried combining a couple of the answers into a section of the code:

```
def max_of_three():

    # Ask users to input values
    value1 = input('Enter the first value here:  \n')
    value2 = input('Enter the second value here:  \n')
    value3 = input('Enter the third value here:  \n')

    # Store values in a list
    maxlist = [value1, value2, value3]
    maxlist.sort()

    # Check for type across the list:
    try:
        typecheck = all(isinstance(item, type(maxlist[0])) for item in maxlist[1:])
    except typecheckerror:
        print('Please ensure all inputs are of the same type!')

    #print the values
    print('\n')
    print('The maximum of these values is: \n', maxlist[-1])

max_of_three()
```

Any pointers on how I could modify this to do what I'm trying to get to? It should return 'c' if I input (a,b,c) and give me the error message if I enter (1,2,a). When I print the value for typecheck, it returns a value of "True" even if I enter something like 1,2,a.

Comment: `input()` should return a string so I'm not sure how `value` could be `True`. What do you get when you run `print([isinstance(item, int) for item in maxlist])` and `print([type(item) for item in maxlist])`

Comment: If this is Python 3, as the tags suggest, input() will always produce a string. (In Python 2, input() will evaluate the user input as Python code instead, so the result might be of arbitrary type). If you want to accept Python syntax (e.g. the user types literally `"foo"` to get a string), pass the result of input() to `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: 'bool' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete code.

```
def check_input_type(value): 
    try:
        value = int(value)
        print(f"Value {value} is an integer!")
        return value
    except ValueError:
        try:
            value = float(value)
            print(f"Value {value} is a float!")
            return value
        except ValueError:
            print(f"Value {value} is a string!")
            return value

def max_of_three():
    max_list = []
    while True:
        value = check_input_type(input(f"Please enter your value : "))
        if not max_list: # if list is empty, append first value.
            max_list.append(value)
        elif type(max_list[0]) == type(value): # checks the next value's type if equal to the first index's type
            max_list.append(value)
        else:
            print("Sorry, I do not understand. Please try again.")
        if len(max_list) != 3:
            continue
        return max_list

listr = max_of_three()

print(f"The maximum of these values {listr} is {max(listr)}!")
```

Comment: I want it to accept str and float inputs as well though, it should return a value of 'c' in the three inputs are a,b,c

Comment: Sorry, I went already to sleep last night. I have edited the code above.

Comment: Thank you, this works wonderfully! I suppose as a thought exercise, if I wanted the function to also check that what a user inputs contains *only* integers, or *only* strings?

Comment: You can use [isnumeric()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) or [isalpha()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) functions to check.

Answer (score 1):

Going by the question title, you can check if *all values are of same type* using:

```
value = all(isinstance(item, type(maxlist[0])) for item in maxlist[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the input value type first by update this section:

```
Value1 = input_int ('Enter the first value here:  \n')
Value2 = input_int ('Enter the second value here:  \n')
Value3 = input_int ('Enter the third value here:  \n')
```

use this custom input function:

```
def input_int(input_msg: str) -> int:
    try:
        val = input(input_msg)
        return int(val)
    except Exception:
        return input_int(input_msg)
```

Comment: When would the recursion stop?

Comment: OK now the code can run, but i'm getting the recursion issue that Austin was referencing.

Comment: sorry the function was updated, cause the input values are strings so that isinstance can't be used in this case

Comment: There's still a recursion issue if I enter a letter rather than a number

Answer (score 0):

The best way  is to actually cast the value into the type you want in a "try/catch".

So if you want to check for integer you would do it like this:

`try:
    val = int(Value1) 
 except ValueError:
    print("This is not a number... Please write a real value")`

You can do the same for float etc as well.

Also you could use isdigit()

```
if(Value1.isdigit()):
   print("Finally, it's a number!")
else:
   print("Type a real number please!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension and compare both:

```
def func(list1):
    list2 = [x for x in list1 if type(x) == int]
    if list1 == list2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

The following section of your code always returns **False**, not True Why? follow the comments

```py
def maxOfThree():
    #Ask users to input values
    # What do you think the data type fo Value1 to 3?
    Value1 = input('Enter the first value here:  \n')
    Value2 = input('Enter the second value here:  \n')
    Value3 = input('Enter the third value here:  \n')
    # When we read any data from user via input() it collect 
    # the data in String data type

    #store values in a list
    # Now you stored all the String into list and applying
    # sort operation on Strings
    maxlist = [Value1, Value2, Value3]
    maxlist.sort()

    #Check for integer type across the list:
    # Now the maxlist contains sorted Strings, Now you are 
    # comparing it's data type with Int which will always
    # fail and it returns **False**
    value = all(isinstance(item, int) for item in maxlist)
    print(value)

    print('\n')
    print('The maximum of these values is: \n', maxlist[-1])

maxOfThree()
```

Example:

```py
Input: 
Enter the first value here:
text
Enter the second value here:
abc
Enter the third value here:
1233
False -> your are comparing list of Strings to Int data type
         with isinstance(item, int)

Output:
The maximum of these values is:
 text
```

Code:

```py
def maxOfThree():
    #Ask users to input values
    Value1 = input('Enter the first value here:  \n')
    Value2 = input('Enter the second value here:  \n')
    Value3 = input('Enter the third value here:  \n')

    #store values in a list by converting to int
    maxlist = []
    # wrapped the conversion code in try block 
    # if any text inputs are given
    try:
        maxlist = [int(each) for each in [Value1, Value2, Value3]]
    except Exception as e:
        print("Couldn't able to convert to integer")
        raise(e)
    maxlist.sort()

    #Check for integer type across the list:
    value = all(isinstance(item, int) for item in maxlist)
    print(value)

    print('\n')
    print('The maximum of these values is: \n', maxlist[-1])

maxOfThree()
```

Comment: Yes, my mistake it returns False by default now.

Comment: The thing is, the function should be able to rank letters as well. So it would return 'c' as the max rank in a list of (a,b,c)

Comment: You meant to say it won't be having a combination of data types? If the same data type across then you function needs to act? and the input may be int, float, string

Comment: Yes that's correct, so if you try to rank (1,2,'a') it would return an error. And ask for another input. But ('d','e','g') should still work